# wp_logout problem

Tags: logout

I have added custom page '/member-logout/' in nav walker for user logout.
When activated then the function 'render-logout' is fired

```
function render_logout() {
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ){
         wp_logout();
    } else {
        echo "You are not logged-in"; 
    }
}
```

the logout works but generates a lot of warnigns of

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at /home/........./formatting.php:5081) in
>   /home/s..../wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 915

and i cannot find what is at fault

but redirect after logout does not work

```
    public function redirect_after_logout() {
    $redirect_url = home_url( 'member-login' );
    wp_redirect( $redirect_url );
    exit;
}
add_action( 'wp_logout', 'redirect_after_logout' );
```

The logout link below works very well (no warnings) but this is not loaded automaticly.

```
<a href="<?php echo wp_logout_url( home_url() ); ?>" title="Logout">Logout</a>
```

Any idea how to run this link using wp_redirect or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom Page template which contains only the logout code, no call to header.php etc. When you load the `/member-logout/` page you're probably calling the default `page.php` template which is loading `header.php` etc. If instead you apply your custom Page template it will just perform the logout action and can then redirect, as no headers have been sent (headers being different than just `header.php` but as soon as you output any HTML, which is contained in `header.php`, you have headers which is preventing the redirect).

Comment: Thank you for info. Quite strange issue with this wp-logout(). I have tested it on three different wordpress instalations (2 localhosts and one online-service) and it works on one local but doesnt on the rest.
Do you think that any other solution exists?
or maybe how to add the link only to the nav walker submenu?

Comment: I do see `wp_logout_url` can take a `redirect` parameter so maybe if you combined it in one call it would make a difference.

Comment: any suggestion how to fire "wp_logout_url( home_url() )" when the page  is loading? 
or maybe  using wp_redirect and wp_logout_url?

Comment: i have tried  "wp_redirect(  wp_logout_url() );"  but logout does not work and still the same warning